# What happens after an action in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this index action:

```
def index

  @registros = find Cid

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @registros }
    format.js
  end
end
```

and when using ajax to call this action, it goes to render index.js.erb file. It's ok. But I need to render application/index.js.erb file, because it is a common file for all views. So I move this file to view/application folder.

But when I did this I had to change my action to:

```
format.js { render "application/index" }
```

Why I had to do this? The default is to look at application folder, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It considers "views/application" as another controller's views, NOT ApplicationController views. In case you share a view between different controllers, it's a bit more logical to put it under `views/shared` and call it from there, and prevent such meanings overlapping. And if you pass only `action_name` as a parameter to render function, Rails will only try to load that file under `controller_name/action_name.format`